# Blazor and ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

I migrated my web app project using guidelines from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio
and now I'm  trying to add simple Blazor component but only thing I'm getting is a static html. What am I missing?

In `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method I have:

```
 services.AddRazorPages(); 
 services.AddMvc();   
 services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` method I have:

```
       app.UseEndpoints(e =>
            {
                e.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                e.MapRazorPages();
                e.MapBlazorHub();
            });
```

and in `_layout.cshtml`:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>

<script>
  Blazor.start({
    configureSignalR: function (builder) {
      builder.configureLogging(2); // LogLevel.Information
    }
  });
```

Browser logs

[image: browser logs]

Comment: How do you render your component?

Comment: <Test>@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Test>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))</Test>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are missing the correct imports:

Add a

```
 _Imports.razor
```

to you projects and fill it with

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks!